# Accidentally deleted node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, terminal

I accidentally deleted my `node_modules` folder.  I know the way to get it back is just to run `npm install` but this won't work in my case.  It's saying something's wrong in my `JSON` file.  I'm getting this error in `Terminal`.

Here's my `Package.js` file:

```
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "aws-sdk": "git://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js.git#react-native",
    "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "^0.45.1",
    "react-native-aws-signature": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-dynamodb": "0.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
    "redux": "^3.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
}
```

Error:

```
Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error on line 27, sufficient `,` here is a valid json

```
{
    "name": "TorusTApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "aws-sdk": "git://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js.git#react-native",
        "react": "^16.0.0-alpha.12",
        "react-native": "^0.45.1",
        "react-native-aws-signature": "0.0.9",
        "react-native-dropdown-menu": "^1.1.0",
        "react-native-dynamodb": "0.0.5",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.5",
        "redux": "^3.7.1"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "2.0.0",
        "jest": "20.0.4",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is because you have an extra comma on the next to last line in your package.js file.

Answer (score 0):

run this json through a json validator online. e.g. https://jsonlint.com/

The previous answer was right but this should help you in the future.